# How to make java use millimeters instead of pixels?

Tags: java, printing, size, lwjgl, image-resizing

My problem is that what I size a picture according to millimeters to pixels, and then print it out this will never be exact.
My question is there a way to make java draw in millimeters or any other metric unit stead of pixels, because pixils will never be exact to millimeters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the screen `DPI` using `java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenResolution();`
Then simply do `(MM * DPI)/25.4`.
 The outcome will be the amount of pixels relative to the physical length in MM.

Comment: Well, at least this time I didn't find my own answer, although it is certainly close :)

Answer (score 1):

Doing some analysis, you could understand better:

```
pixels = mm * inch/mm * pixels/inch
pixels = mm (milimeters) * 25.4 (how many inches I have in 1 mm) * DPI (screen resolution)
```

DPI is dots per inch, which is the same of pixels per inch.